# How to programmatically check whether eclipse console build or GUI build is launched?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I am writing CDT plug-in for Eclipse IDE. I want to show a warning dialog to user if GUI Eclipse instance is launched, otherwise if console build is launched just write to stderr. How can I determine programmatically which of GUI and console Eclipse is launched?

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: This code works properly only if a corresponding system property is set.

```
boolean isHeadless = System.getProperty("eclipse.application")
            .equals("org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild");
```

This code checks an argument passed as an "application", it is "org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild" in case of a headless eclipse launch.

Answer (score 0):

You could also check SWT plugin's state:

```
Bundle swtBunble = Platform.getBundle("org.eclipse.swt");
boolean isHeadless = (swtBunble==null || swtBunble.getState() != Bundle.ACTIVE);
```

Comment: alt3, also did not work, swtBundle != null and its getState() returns Bundle.RESOLVED in both cases.

Comment: That seems strange to me. If the bundle is resolved but not active, how has SWT loaded?